# Stop text from leaking out of div

Tags: html, css, text

I have some text which is contained in a div, however if it's too long, it leaks outside of the div and I don't want that. I dont want to use the overflow attribute and give it a scroll bar. Id like it to put the "..." at the end of the text to indicate that there's more text at the end that's not displaying. The user can then see the full text when they hover over it.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Google css ellipsis https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the overflow-ellipsis class to your element:

```
.overflow-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

example of text-overflow..check it
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_textoverflow.asp